# Convert JavaScript button for lightning!

Tags: lightning, javascript, button, convert

I have a JavaScript button which works fine in classic but doesn't show up in lightning, my guess that JavaScript buttons are not supported in lightning, I couldn't convert it using the converter since it is complicated, how can I write it to accomplish the same functionality, this is the button, it is called Pay Now (Partially):

```
{!requireScript("/soap/ajax/32.0/connection.js")} 

function isEmpty(val){ 
return (val === undefined || val == null || val.length <= 0) ? true : false; 
} 


var region = '{!PBSI__PBSI_Sales_Order__c.Stripe_Region__c }'; 

if(isEmpty(region)) 
{ 
region = '{!User.RegionText__c}'; 
} 

result = sforce.connection.query("Select Id from fw1__Payment_Processor__c WHERE Name='" + region + "'"); 
records = result.getArray("records"); 
if (result == null || result.size < 1) { 

/*alert('You need to setup the payment processor for this region (' + region + ') before making payment'); 
} else {*/
result=''
} 

var payment; 
payment = prompt('Please enter the payment amount.'); 
var RE = /^-{0,1}\d*\.{0,1}\d+$/; 
if(RE.test(payment)){ 

window.open('/apex/fw1__Payment?amount='+payment+'&accountId={!PBSI__PBSI_Sales_Order__c.PBSI__CustomerId__c}&lookupField=Sales_Order__c&lookupId={!PBSI__PBSI_Sales_Order__c.Id}&reference={!PBSI__PBSI_Sales_Order__c.Name}&contactId={!PBSI__PBSI_Sales_Order__c.PBSI__ContactId__c}&Currency={!PBSI__PBSI_Sales_Order__c.CurrencyIsoCode}&Lookupobject=PBSI__PBSI_Sales_Order__c&Description1={!PBSI__PBSI_Sales_Order__c.PBSI__Customer__c}&Description2=Final+Order+Value=+{!PBSI__PBSI_Sales_Order__c.Final_Order_Total_From_Quote2__c}&processor='+region+'&paidAmountField=Paid_Amount__c', '_blank', 'width=640,height=480'); 

} 
else{ 
alert('Invalid number'); 
}
```

Comment: Hey Roody Welcome to SFSE, What you have tried so far?

Comment: I haven't tried anything, I will try to make a lightning component and put this logic inside its controller and see how it will work.

Comment: make that lightning component as lightning quick action, here is the [link](http://sfdcmonkey.com/2017/04/16/add-lightning-component-lightning-action/) that might help you.

Comment: I did that, and got this error: Action failed: c:PayNow$controller$doInit [requireScript is not defined]
The required script is mentioned in line 1 from the code I wrote, it looks like it is not recognized.

Comment: Ok, you need not to add required script, for query part you have to move it to apex side : create @AuraEnabled method to make query and call it from your component, for inputs you need to use lightning:input tag.

Comment: also you need to add two buttons : for Ok and Cancel like they are in JS prompt, on click of 'Ok' you can add your logic to open window

Answer (score 3):

There are various guides/examples available for how to do this work. Two good ones I know of are:

- Trailhead's [Lightning Alternatives to JavaScript Buttons](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_javascript_button_migration)
- Bayforce's [Converting JavaScript Buttons for Lightning Experience](https://www.bayforce.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/Bayforce-JavaScript-Lightning-Experience-White-Paper.pdf)